# Возращаемый тип универсальной стуруктуры. Rust

Tags: rust

Как сделать так, чтобы универсальный конструктор возвращал структуру с полем любого типа, который разделяет какую-нибудь числовую характеристику?

```rust
struct Point<T>(T);

impl<T> Point<T> {

fn new() -> Point<T> {
 Point(100)
}
}
fn main() {
  let y = Point::new();
  println!("{:?}", y.0);
}


--> main.rs:9:8
  |
9 |  Point(100)
  |        ^^^ expected type parameter, found integer
  |
  = note: expected type `T`
             found type `{integer}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно воспользоваться подходящим ограничением типа. Например, подойдёт `From<u8>`:

```rust
struct Point<T>(T);

impl<T: From<u8>> Point<T> {
    fn new() -> Point<T> {
        Point(T::from(100))
    }
}
```

Ещё можно вот так сделать:

```rust
impl<T: From<u8>> Point<T> {
    fn new() -> Point<T> {
        Point(100.into())
    }
}
```

Comment: благодарю.
То есть, если понадобится, чтобы конструктор создавал структуру с полем большего размера, чем u8, то придется менять сигнатуру?